# Segmentation fault: 11 during pandas to_csv operation

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm working on Mac OS 10.10.5, using a Python 2.7 virtualenv and pandas installed via pip.

I have a Pandas dataFrame (called 'pivot') which is 13843 rows by 40 columns. Most of the data cells are single characters (A, B, C or D).

I am trying to export this to a csv file using the command:

```
pivot.to_csv(path_or_buf="test.csv",sep=",", encoding='utf-8')
```

The output CSV gets to row 8743, which is truncated after the 8th column, and the program crashes out with a Segmentation fault: 11

It shouldn't be a memory problem, as my Mac has 16Gb RAM.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Try to find the minimum reproducing example.  `iloc` may come in handy, e.g. `pivot.iloc[8000:9000, 10:20]` and so on.  (Although since this is a segfault, and so basically a bug report, to be honest it's probably best handled on github rather than here.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion re. Github. I've posted the issue here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11174

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an issue with the data. There were instances where I was trying to pivot duplicate data rows.