# Pandas pivot table breaking due to segmentation fault 11

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a pivot table using pandas via the following script.

```
def analyzefile(file):
        a = pd.read_csv(file,header=None,names=labels,engine='python')
        df = pd.pivot_table(a,index=["STATE_SENATE_DISTRICT"], aggfunc='count',chunksize=300000)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('zipBreakout.xlsx')
        df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
        writer.save()

analyzefile('FilteredDistricts.csv')
```

This code returns `Segmentation fault: 11`. It should be noted that the data set that I'm working with is quite large ~1.3 million entries. Is there a way to chunk the data so this doesn't happen? Another solution?

Comment: One suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720514/segmentation-fault-11-during-pandas-to-csv-operation) is that you have duplicate entries but I don't know if that's related. On an unrelated note, the maximum number of rows that Excel will allow is 1,048,576 so I'm not sure whether that will cause an issue or if the file will even be possible to open.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution equal to pivot_table is `groupby`.  Not really sure if this will solve your problem but you can try:

```
df = a.groupby('STATE_SENATE_DISTRICT').count()
```